# Every time open app , open last open activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Sir,
    The last opened activity will be saved and when opening the app, the last opened activity will be opened. But app reopen every time  then see splash screen then go last open activity, Please help me for it..

Please send this code

Comment: You gave the answer already in the question. Save last opened location, and when the app starts again read that saved information and start the respective activity.

Comment: @Henry , send code

Comment: I am not an android developer I have not studied about this, I studied through internet, you have to help me, the code you send me  please ,I will be witting , hop you will send the code

Comment: Asking for code is off-topic for this site.

Comment: I asking , I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

That's simple. When the activity is closed, in the activity class, override the onStop() method and save the activity name in the SharedPreferences. Then in the main activity, get the SharedPreferences variable and open the activity using an intent. Hope this helps. For more info, ping using a comment. I'll share the working code.

Comment: I am not an android developer I have not studied about this, I studied through internet, you have to help me, the code you send me  please ,I will be witting , hop you will send the code

Comment: Sir any help me?

Comment: @Shabab Probably nobody will send you the code because stackoverflow is not a writing code service and usually these "give me the code" type of questions are closed as they are considered off topic: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262103/how-to-close-please-write-code-type-questions?__=1086867225. Also take a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"questions must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."*